# Calculating between-group inequality without microdata

Tags: inequality

I have data about a few (subnational) geographical units. For each of these units, I know:

1) the proportion of workers by level of education

2) the average income by level of education

3) the average income for the all the population (across all levels of education)

I do not have access to micro-data, and I realise that this prevents me from taking within-group inequality into account.

That being said, what would be a way to calculate between-group (level of education) inequality, so I can compare its values across units?

Comment: Do you know about the Gini Coefficient? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiniCoefficient.html

Comment: I think it is still unclear what you are aiming for. Could you specify (mathematically) the exact variable you are trying to estimate?

Comment: @Ubiquitous I know about the Gini Coefficient, but my data do not allow me to calculate it, as I do not have information about individual level income, only group averages.

Comment: @HREcon I'm afraid that not being an economist and not having a good mathematical background, I am not able to specify the variable I am trying to estimate. Let me try to make it more clear: I realise that some inequality measures are decomposable into two components: between-group inequality and within-group inequality. Given that I only have group-level information, I would like to be able to extract a measure of between-group inequality which also takes into account the proportions of each group in the population.